# cURL - Return page source code and display as text only

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I'm using cURL to get page source. It works great, but when I use

```
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($source);
echo '</pre>';
```

to display as text only, the page gets parsed and I end up seeing it as a webpage instead of plain text.

How can I view the remote page as text only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your HTML needs to be escaped in what you are outputting, example:

```
echo '<pre>';
print(htmlspecialchars($source));
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Will this safely display ALL code as text no matter what's on the other end of the connection? Image, redirect headers, malicious files or executables?

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to inject something malicious into that.